# Multiline Hex to Decimal converter

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I'm trying to make a hex to decimal converter for large amounts of hex numbers.

```
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("-", "");
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "");
        if (textBox1.TextLength > 0)
        {
            textBox2.Text = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString();
        }
        textBox3.Text = textBox2.Text.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ");
    }
```

works fine on single line.
Error when trying to convert multiple lines

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Hi @Craigmatt and welcome to Stackoverflow! A few questions regarding the code you have: 1) Is the textbox1 a multiline textbox? 2) Do you need to handle all the text of that textbox as a single HEX string, or you'd like create a hex string for each of the lines separately?

Comment: Hi @JustShadow. 1) Both text boxes are Multiline. 2) In the first text box there would a large amount of hex numbers over multiple lines with a - in the middle. e.g. line 1 = 0001-0001, line 2 = 0001-000A, using         textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("-", "");
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", ""); to clear any spaces and -'s before converting the number to decimal. Textbox 2 to show Decimal value. Textbox 3 to show decimal values to string with , separating

Comment: Okay, so another set of questions: 1) Do you use new-lines in the textboxes (hit enter there)? 2) Can you please check if the same code works fine for the shorter hex strings. Something like this: "AADF-----------------------------------------------------AA". (Here I'm using lots of -es to make the string longer, and start a new line, but the hex string itself is short).

Comment: I have a few ideas in my mind, just want to clarify the case before providing the solutions

Comment: 1) Each new line will be an enter.  2) using "AADF-----------------------------------------------------AA" this returns "11198378". I do have this in to remove -es textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("-", "");

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a multiline textbox, try replacing the newline characters of its' value as well, like this:

```
  textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", ""); // For Windows
  textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("\n", ""); // For Unix/Linux
```